# Efficient (dense) multivariate polynomial multiplication

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math

Suppose we have two polynomials, in man variables, but they need not both contain the same variables. But, for the variables a polynomial does contain, it contains all monomials (up to a degree).

#### Example up to degree 2

> Polynomial A: 1+x+y+x^2+xy+y^2
>
> Polynomial B: 1+e+f+e^2+ef+f^2

Both A and B are of degree 2, and they are both dense, meaning they contain all monomials of their respected variables.

Note that in the above, the sets of variables A_s=(x,y) and B_s=(e,f) had an empty intersection, but that need not be the case.

Does anybody know of an efficient algorithm for computing their product? As both polynomials are dense, there must be an algorithm that takes advantage of this fact.

I have an algorithm, that is efficient, if the above sets of variables A_s == B_s, are equal. The trivial solution of simply expanding the sets, giving zero coeficients, ex.

> A: 1+x+y+0e+0f+...

is not a valid one, as one would constantly need to construct new arrays (polynomial representations).

Comment: The fft will take care of that if you are working numerically.

Comment: The problem with FFT is that the polynomial length has to be a power of 2 (padded with zeros), which is a similar problem to the one mentioned in my last paragraph. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: yes, but it's still way faster than anything else i can imagine

Comment: i'm not completely sure about it, that's why i answered as a comment, not an answer.